# Removing everything after last hyphen in a string in Bash script?

Tags: string, bash

Working on a script where I need to take a string, and remove everything after the **last** occurence of a certain character. In this case a hyphen.

For example, `This-is-a-filename-0001.jpg` should result in `This-is-a-filename`

Comment: Please add to your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: Start with looking at something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/918886/4961700

Answer (score 5):

You can cut strings in bash:

```
line="This-is-a-filename-0001.jpg"
echo "${line%-*}" # prints: This-is-a-filename
```

The `%-*`operator removes all beginning with the last hyphen.

Answer (score -1):

You're looking for a `sed` within your script, something close to what's below.

```
sed 's!/[^/]*$!/!'
```

Generally, I would say, please do research before posting a question like yours since it's relatively easy to find the answers

Comment: It is useful to wait with the answer until the questioner has shown what he has done to answer the question himself.

Comment: Why would you use any external command for something the shell can do built-in? This is much slower to run than using built-in [parameter expansion](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe). And because this example is searching on `/`s instead of `-`s, it's not responsive to the question as-asked.